# What's the easiest way to prepend the current time to the fish prompt?

Tags: shell, prompt, fish

I'd like to see the current time in my fish prompt so that I can always see for example when I started the last command. I don't want to install extensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `~/.config/fish/functions` there is a file named `fish_prompt.fish`. Replace the line

```
    echo -n (prompt_pwd)
```

with

```
    echo -n (date +%H:%M) (prompt_pwd)
```

Result:

[image: Result]